# How long would it take python to generate a million different numbers?

Tags: python

Is python able to generate a million random numbers with code

```
import random
a = random.randint(1, 50)
for i in range(1000000):
    print(a)
```

And if it can, approximately how long would it take?

Comment: You are generating a single number there. Also, even when generating that many numbers, the bottleneck in your code would be the call to `print`, as IO is pretty costly.

Comment: You could also check for `randint` of `numpy`'s random package; it provides a third parameter to set the shape of the output, hence: one million here. `a = np.random.randint(1, 50, 1000000)`

Answer (score 2):

It takes 0.92 seconds on my laptop.

```
from timeit import timeit
timeit(lambda:[ random.randint(1,50) for _ in range(1000000) ], number=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can. Test it with time library.

```
import time
import random
from random import randint
start = time.time()
for i in range(1000000):
    a = random.randint(1, 50)
end = time.time()
print('It took ' + str(end-start) +' seconds to generate 1000000 numbers')
```

It was 0.986739158630371 seconds for me, however printing out the numbers slowed the process very much, so I don't recommend printing them.

You have to put the random number generator inside the loop, otherwise it won't be changing during the run.

Comment: `from random import randint` is not needed (you could use it, but you're not using it in your code).

Answer (score 1):

Note that your code generates only one random integer, then prints it a million times.

You have to call `randint()` *inside* the loop if you want to generate a million random numbers.

That said, depending on details of which version of Python you're using and your hardware, simply generating a million random integers shouldn't take more than a few seconds.  In the code you showed, it would take a lot longer to *print* them.

Answer (score 0):

Your code now will always print the same number over and over because you only generate it once and then print it a million times.

```
import random
for i in range(1000000):
    a = random.randint(1, 50)
    print(a)
```

This will make it so that every time you loop you will generate a new number.
And as for speed, just try it it wont take long.